# How to access query string parameters inside IFRAME after a redirect back

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an HTML `Host1Page` with an IFRAME, the IFRAME's attribute `sandbox` doesn't include `allow-top-navigation` so the hosting page is not affected by any navigation which could be requested inside the IFRAME. Originally the IFRAME renders static HTML I supply but then, once a user interacts with it in a certain way, the HTML's javascript redirects the current window, which is the IFRAME's content in my case, to another host - `Host2Page`. As a result the IFRAME renders a content of the `Host2Page`. Want to emphasis I'm not setting the IFRAME's `src` property but instead setting the `window.location.href`, I cannot change the way the redirect is done because I don't own the code making that redirect. Once a user finishes interacting with that another site, `Host2Page`, the user is redirected back to the Uri corresponding to the page hosting my IFRAME - `Host1Page`, while redirecting the `Host2Page` is supplying some data via query parameters. **How do I get access to that query parameter from within the IFRAME?**

I tried employing `myIFrame.contentWindow.location.search` - but it always is empty and the `myIFrame.contentWindow.location.href` is always, before and after the redirect to that another site, pointing to the Uri of the page `Host1Page` hosting the IFRAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the content of the IFRAME that's being loaded after the second redirect, you could use `postMessage` to send the parameter values to the parent page.

```
const querystringParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const querystringValue = querystringParams.get('paramINeed');

window.parent.postMessage(querystringValue, targetOrigin);
```

To receive the message on your parent page:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

with `receiveMessage` being a function which takes an event object as a parameter.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Where do i get the `targetOrigin`?